# Delete option on suggested edits queue doesn't do anything

Tags: bug, status-norepro, review, suggested-edits, moderator-abilities

There's a delete option next to each post on suggested edits queue (for moderators)

---

[image: Delete on suggested edit]

For this [suggested edit](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/6431), the best option is to delete the entire post, so I click on the delete button. But, despite clicking on delete, the post still remains and the suggested edit is also pending

---

[image: vote to delete]

---

[image: still remains after delete]

Comment: aha ... my bug will sort it (note this is a mod only feature)

Comment: I got no repro here ... just tested it out ... which chrome are you using?

Comment: @waffles Chrome stable on Windows 7 Ed: Just tried on a dummy post, can't repro either

Comment: need to figure out if this is a once off deployment artefact or reproducible ...

Answer (score 1):

Since no activity has occurred here in nearly 3 years, I'm assuming a reliable repro couldn't be found.

Comment: well, we have completely different UI too for this.